# Merge Candidates: [apex] and [apex-code]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

These tags are possibly the same thing.

[image: candiates]

[Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apex-code/info) for [apex-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex-code).
[Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apex/info) for [apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex).

Comment: As a Salesforce Developer, I agree that these two tags can be merged.